# Numpy fancy indexing question about specific array and its final shape?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, reshape

```
X = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4)) => shape (3,4)
row = np.array([0, 1, 2])
row[:, np.newaxis] => shape (3,1)

X[row[:, np.newaxis], :]  => shape (3,1,4)
```

Can anyone explain how this final shape occurs, when according to the "rules of broadcasting" the shapes of the indices broadcasted is supposed to be the final shape?

Comment: The 2nd index is a slice, not another array.  Broadcasting doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `X[i, :]` gives the i-th row of `X` as array of shape `(X.shape[1],)`
- `X[[i], :]` gives the i-th row of `X` as array of shape `(1, X.shape[1])`
- `X[[[i]], :]` gives the i-th row of `X` as array of shape `(1, 1, X.shape[1])`
- `X[[[[i]]], :]` gives the i-th row of `X` as array of shape `(1, 1, 1, X.shape[1])`
- ...

As you can see, in this way you are simply introducing extra dimensions and the shape of the output array is the shape of the index-array + the shape of the row of `X`.

Now, the `row[:, np.newaxis]` is `array([[0], [1], [2]])` and has shape `(3,1)` and each row of X has shape `(4,)`. So `X[[[0], [1], [2]], :]` returns the three rows of X packed into array of shape `(3,1) + (4,) = (3, 1, 4)`.